# Custom 404 page running 3 times

Tags: iis, web

I have a custom 404 page , and on it I run a script to insert a record into a db with the page name.
I am noticing that each page gets written to my db 3 times, like it's hitting the page 3 times.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the steps I would take to troubleshoot this issue. Without facts it's hard to determine what might be wrong. Here are some steps you can do to gather more facts.

1. Take a look at your IIS Logs to confirm the 404 page is being hit 3 times.
2. If the above is true, then it's not the script and you should be able to determine what's going on by following the sequence in the IIS Logs.
3. If it is the script, then provide the script to be analyzed.